# Implementing the Choice Type in C#

Tags: c#, linq, f#, functional-programming, monads

for educational reasons I'm trying to implement the Choice and the Option Type from F# in C#. This was inspired by the book "Real World Functional Programming" and some blog posts like: http://bugsquash.blogspot.de/2011/08/refactoring-to-monadic-c-applicative.html and http://tomasp.net/blog/idioms-in-linq.aspx/.

I would like to get this to work, but I don't know how to implement the Extensions for the Choice Type (Bind, Map, SelectMany, ...):

```
public static void Division()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter two (floating point) numbers:");

    (
        from f1 in ReadDouble().ToChoice("Could not parse input to a double.")
        from f2 in ReadDouble().ToChoice("Could not parse input to a double.")
        from result in Divide(f1, f2).ToChoice("Cannot divide by zero.")
        select result
    )
        .Match(
            x => Console.WriteLine("Result = {0}", x),
            x => Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", x));
}

public static Option<double> Divide(double a, double b)
{
    return b == 0 ? Option.None<double>() : Option.Some(a / b);
}

public static Option<Double> ReadDouble()
{
    double i;
    if (Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i))
        return Option.Some(i);
    else
        return Option.None<double>();
}

    public static Option<int> ReadInt()
    {
        int i;
        if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i))
            return Option.Some(i);
        else
            return Option.None<int>();
    }
}
```

The Option Type looks like this:

```
public enum OptionType
{
    Some, None
}

public abstract class Option<T>
{
    private readonly OptionType _tag;

    protected Option(OptionType tag)
    {
        _tag = tag;
    }

    public OptionType Tag { get { return _tag; } }

    internal bool MatchNone()
    {
        return Tag == OptionType.None;
    }

    internal bool MatchSome(out T value)
    {
        value = Tag == OptionType.Some ? ((Some<T>)this).Value : default(T);
        return Tag == OptionType.Some;
    }

    public void Match(Action<T> onSome, Action onNone)
    {
        if (Tag == OptionType.Some)
            onSome(((Some<T>)this).Value);
        else
            onNone();
    }

    public Choice<T, T2> ToChoice<T2>(T2 value)
    {
        if (Tag == OptionType.Some)
        {
            T some;
            MatchSome(out some);
            return Choice.NewChoice1Of2<T, T2>(some);
        }
        else
            return Choice.NewChoice2Of2<T, T2>(value);
    }
}

internal class None<T> : Option<T>
{
    public None() : base(OptionType.None) { }
}

internal class Some<T> : Option<T>
{
    public Some(T value)
        : base(OptionType.Some)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
    private readonly T _value;
    public T Value { get { return _value; } }
}

public static class Option
{
    public static Option<T> None<T>()
    {
        return new None<T>();
    }
    public static Option<T> Some<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Some<T>(value);
    }
}

public static class OptionExtensions
{
    public static Option<TResult> Map<T, TResult>(this Option<T> source, Func<T, TResult> selector)
    {
        T value;
        return source.MatchSome(out value) ? Option.Some(selector(value)) : Option.None<TResult>();
    }

    public static Option<TResult> Bind<T, TResult>(this Option<T> source, Func<T, Option<TResult>> selector)
    {
        T value;
        return source.MatchSome(out value) ? selector(value) : Option.None<TResult>();
    }

    public static Option<TResult> Select<T, TResult>(this Option<T> source, Func<T, TResult> selector)
    {
        return source.Map(selector);
    }

    public static Option<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TValue, TResult>(this Option<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Option<TValue>> valueSelector, Func<TSource, TValue, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        return source.Bind(s => valueSelector(s).Map(v => resultSelector(s, v)));
    }
}
```

And here is the Choice Type Implementation:

```
public enum ChoiceType { Choice1Of2, Choice2Of2 };

public abstract class Choice<T1, T2>
{
    private readonly ChoiceType _tag;

    protected Choice(ChoiceType tag)
    {
        _tag = tag;
    }

    public ChoiceType Tag { get { return _tag; } }

    internal bool MatchChoice1Of2(out T1 value)
    {
        value = Tag == ChoiceType.Choice1Of2 ? ((Choice1Of2<T1, T2>)this).Value : default(T1);
        return Tag == ChoiceType.Choice1Of2;
    }

    internal bool MatchChoice2Of2(out T2 value)
    {
        value = Tag == ChoiceType.Choice2Of2 ? ((Choice2Of2<T1, T2>)this).Value : default(T2);
        return Tag == ChoiceType.Choice2Of2;
    }

    public void Match(Action<T1> onChoice1Of2, Action<T2> onChoice2Of2)
    {
        if (Tag == ChoiceType.Choice1Of2)
            onChoice1Of2(((Choice1Of2<T1, T2>)this).Value);
        else
            onChoice2Of2(((Choice2Of2<T1, T2>)this).Value);
    }
}

internal class Choice1Of2<T1, T2> : Choice<T1, T2>
{
    public Choice1Of2(T1 value)
        : base(ChoiceType.Choice1Of2)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
    private readonly T1 _value;

    public T1 Value { get { return _value; } }
}

internal class Choice2Of2<T1, T2> : Choice<T1, T2>
{
    public Choice2Of2(T2 value)
        : base(ChoiceType.Choice2Of2)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
    private readonly T2 _value;

    public T2 Value { get { return _value; } }
}

public static class Choice
{
    public static Choice<T1, T2> NewChoice1Of2<T1, T2>(T1 value)
    {
        return new Choice1Of2<T1, T2>(value);
    }

    public static Choice<T1, T2> NewChoice2Of2<T1, T2>(T2 value)
    {
        return new Choice2Of2<T1, T2>(value);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It actually works with the Extensions below. What I don't really like about it is that this implementation adds a context specific behaviour to the Choice type. This is because the Choice1Of2 is the prefered choice because all the extension methods mainly operate on it rather than on Choice2Of2 or both. (But that's what the consuming code actually implies, so I guess it is the only way to get it working.)

```
public static Choice<TResult, T2> Map<T1, T2, TResult>(this Choice<T1, T2> source, Func<T1, TResult> selector)
{
    T1 value1;
    if(source.MatchChoice1Of2(out value1))
    {
        return Choice.NewChoice1Of2<TResult, T2>(selector(value1));
    }

    T2 value2;
    if (source.MatchChoice2Of2(out value2))
    {
        return Choice.NewChoice2Of2<TResult, T2>(value2);
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("source (:Choice) has no value.");
}

public static Choice<TResult, T2> Bind<T1, T2, TResult>(this Choice<T1, T2> source, Func<T1, Choice<TResult, T2>> selector)
{
    T1 value1;
    if (source.MatchChoice1Of2(out value1))
    {
        return selector(value1);
    }

    T2 value2;
    if (source.MatchChoice2Of2(out value2))
    {
        return Choice.NewChoice2Of2<TResult, T2>(value2);
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("source (:Choice) has no value.");
}

public static Choice<TResult, T2> Select<T1, T2, TResult>(this Choice<T1, T2> source, Func<T1, TResult> selector)
{
    return source.Map(selector);
}

public static Choice<TResult, T2> SelectMany<TSource, TValue, T2, TResult>(this Choice<TSource, T2> source, Func<TSource, Choice<TValue, T2>> valueSelector, Func<TSource, TValue, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return source.Bind(s => valueSelector(s).Map(v => resultSelector(s, v)));
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: For the code in the first sample to work, the compiler is looking for implementation of Select and SelectMany in the Choice Type. I don't know how to implement them. In the Option type it worked fine but in the choice don't you need two selector functions for both the T1 and T2 types of choice. How would that work?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/sasa/code/ci/default/tree/Sasa/Either2.cs

Comment: Hi @mauricio, thanks. But I'm missing the implementations of Select and SelectMany which I am especially interested in.

Comment: @user1993065 they're trivial to write as extension methods.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I updated my original post. This way it works. I just thought it is a little strange because this is context specific because the selector functions are applied only to choice1of2. But I guess that's the only way...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Choice` has two type parameters, you need to fix the first one to be able to write `Select` and `SelectMany` (bind):

```
public abstract class Choice<T1, T2>
{
    public abstract Choice<T1, T3> Select<T3>(Func<T2, T3> f);
    public abstract Choice<T1, T3> SelectMany<T3>(Func<T2, Choice<T1, T3>> f);
}
```

their implementation is straightforward for `Choice1Of2`:

```
public override Choice<T1, T3> Select<T3>(Func<T2, T3> f)
{
    return new Choice1Of2<T1, T3>(this._value);
}

public override Choice<T1, T3> SelectMany<T3>(Func<T2, Choice<T1, T3>> f)
{
    return new Choice1Of2<T1, T3>(this._value);
}
```

and for `Choice2Of2` you just need to provide the inner value to the given function:

```
public override Choice<T1, T3> Select<T3>(Func<T2, T3> f)
{
    return new Choice2Of2<T1, T3>(f(this.Value));
}
public override Choice<T1, T3> SelectMany<T3>(Func<T2, Choice<T1, T3>> f)
{
    return f(this._value);
}
```

You may also want a `BiSelect` function for mapping over both type parameters:

```
public abstract BiSelect<T3, T4>(Func<T1, T3> ff, Func<T2, T4> fs);
```

If you want to use `SelectMany` with the linq query syntax, you need to implement another overload which looks like:

```
public abstract Choice<T1, T4> SelectMany<T3, T4>(Func<T2, Choice<T1, T3>> f, Func<T2, T3, T4> selector);
```

The implementation for `Choice1Of2` is similar to before:

```
public override Choice<T1, T4> SelectMany<T3, T4>(Func<T2, Choice<T1, T3>> f, Func<T2, T3, T4> selector)
{
    return new Choice1Of2<T1, T4>(this._value);
}
```

The implementation for `Choice2Of2` is then:

```
public override Choice<T1, T4> SelectMany<T3, T4>(Func<T2, Choice<T1, T3>> f, Func<T2, T3, T4> selector)
{
    T2 val = this._value;
    var e = f(val);
    return e.Select(v => selector(val, v));
}
```

and you can do:

```
var choice = from x in new Choice2Of2<string, int>(1)
             from y in new Choice2Of2<string, int>(4)
             select x + y;
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. Although, this code like it is posted here doesn't seem to work.

Comment: On this line `from v1 in ReadDouble().ToChoice("Could not parse input.")` I get this error: `Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Choice<double,string>'.  'SelectMany' not found.` - I posted a working solution in my original post. Probably the parameters of the SelectMany Function are not correct.

Comment: @user1993065 - There's another overload of `SelectMany` required for the query syntax, see update.

Comment: Yes, this should work. Actually that's what I came up with, too. Except I implemented those functions as extensions and I applied the selector function to the Choice1Of2 as opposed to Choice2Of2.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one new extensions class to make 'Match' method works on IEnumerable

```
public static class ChoiceExtensions
{

    // You need this method, because code 'select result' is a LINQ expression and it returns IEnumerable
    public static void Match<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<Choice<T1, T2>> seq, Action<T1> onChoice1Of2, Action<T2> onChoice2Of2)
    {
        foreach (var choice in seq)
        {
            choice.Match(onChoice1Of2, onChoice2Of2);
        }
    }

    // This method will help with the complex matching
    public static Choice<T1, T2> Flat<T1, T2>(this Choice<Choice<T1, T2>, T2> choice)
    {
        Choice<T1, T2> result = null;

        choice.Match(
            t1 => result = t1,
            t2 => result = new Choice2Of2<T1, T2>(t2));

        return result;
    }
}
```

Also, I've changed your Choice class:

```
// Implement IEnumerable to deal with LINQ
public abstract class Choice<T1, T2> : IEnumerable<Choice<T1, T2>>
{
    IEnumerator<Choice<T1, T2>> IEnumerable<Choice<T1, T2>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return this;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return this;
    }

    // These two methods work with your Devide function
    // I think, it is good to throw an exception here, if c is not a choice of 1
    public static implicit operator T1(Choice<T1, T2> c)
    {
        T1 val;
        c.MatchChoice1Of2(out val);
        return val;
    }

    // And you can add exception here too
    public static implicit operator T2(Choice<T1, T2> c)
    {
        T2 val;
        c.MatchChoice2Of2(out val);
        return val;
    }

    // Your Match method returns void, it is not good in functional programming,
    // because, whole purpose of the method returning void is the change state,
    // and in FP state is immutable
    // That's why I've created PureMatch method for you
    public Choice<T1Out, T2Out> PureMatch<T1Out, T2Out>(Func<T1, T1Out> onChoice1Of2, Func<T2, T2Out> onChoice2Of2)
    {
        Choice<T1Out, T2Out> result = null;

        Match(
            t1 => result = new Choice1Of2<T1Out, T2Out>(onChoice1Of2(t1)),
            t2 => result = new Choice2Of2<T1Out, T2Out>(onChoice2Of2(t2)));

        return result;
    }

    // Continue Choice class
}
```

Your sample is slightly incorrect, because when you write:

```
from f1 in ReadDouble().ToChoice("Could not parse input to a double.")
from f2 in ReadDouble().ToChoice("Could not parse input to a double.")
from result in Devide(f1, f2).ToChoice("Cannot devide by zero.")
select result
```

in the last line you actually ignore f1 and f2. So it is impossible to see parsing error. Better write:

```
        (
            from f1 in ReadDouble().ToChoice("Could not parse input to a double.")
            from f2 in ReadDouble().ToChoice("Could not parse input to a double.")
            from result in
                f1.PureMatch(
                    f1value => f2.PureMatch(
                        f2value => Devide(f1, f2).ToChoice("Cannot devide by zero."),
                        f2err => f2err).Flat(),
                    f1err => f1err
                ).Flat()
            select result
        )
            .Match(
                x => Console.WriteLine("Result = {0}", x),
                x => Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", x));
```

You can create nice helper methods to deal with this complicated stuff, something like PureMatch method but with more arguments

Comment: Thanks, this works. But it doesn't behave like I expected... By the way, I don't like overriding the implicit operator so much because this could return null or throw an exception...

Comment: I think it would be better to implicitly convert to Option<T1> like this `public static implicit operator Option<T1>(Choice<T1, T2> c) {...}`

Comment: "Your Match method returns void, it is not good in functional programming" -> that is a very good point, thx!